How to apply an event listener to multiple elements sharing ID, but only firing on the parent of the clicked element
I'm trying to develop an inspection form where a 'corrective action' prompt is fired when the 'X' radio is selected rather than the 'checkmark' radio.
I've used event listeners on both buttons to fire the prompt when necessary.
What I'm trying to accomplish is to use this function over multiple DIV's rather than write specific event listeners for each section (this would result in a ton of code as I intend to have a lot of points on the inspection form). I'm hoping there is a way to share the ID's for all the sections, and attach the event listeners to ALL IDs, but only fire the 'corrective action' prompt within the parent DIV the radio was selected. (I hope this makes sense).
note The inputs for the Registration Line share the same ID as the inputs in the Insurance Line
**<!--Registration Line-->**
<div class="accordion-body vehicleBody border border-light-subtle">
    <h3 id="registration" class="mx-3">Current / Valid Vehicle Registration
        <span>
        <input type="radio" class="btn-check reg" name="registration" id="success" autocomplete="off" >
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success rounded-circle" for="success"><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></label>
        <input  type="radio" class="btn-check" name="registration" id="danger" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-danger rounded-circle ms-3" for="danger"><i class="fa-solid fa-x"></i></label>
        </span>
    </h3>
    <div class="ms-3" id="correctiveAction">
        <p class="text-center" style="font-weight: 400; padding: 10px; color: crimson; text-decoration: underline;">Corrective Action Required!</p>
        <div class="form-floating correctiveAction" >
            <textarea class="form-control" id="floatingTextarea2" style="height: 100px"></textarea>
            <label for="floatingTextarea2">Please determine appropriate corrective action.</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mt-2 ">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i></span>
            <span class="input-group-text infoHead" style="width:174px;">Responsible Person:</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="employee name" aria-describedby="employee name">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Insurance Line-->
<div class="accordion-body vehicleBody border border-light-subtle">
    <h3 id="insurance" class="mx-3">Current / Valid Insurance
        <span>
        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="insurance" id="success" autocomplete="off">
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success rounded-circle" for="success"><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="insurance" id="danger" autocomplete="off">
        <label class="btn btn-outline-danger rounded-circle ms-3" for="danger"><i class="fa-solid fa-x"></i></label>
        </span>
    </h3>
    <div class="ms-3" id="correctiveAction">
        <p class="text-center" style="font-weight: 400; padding: 10px; color: crimson; text-decoration: underline;">Corrective Action Required!</p>
        <div class="form-floating correctiveAction" >
            <textarea class="form-control" id="floatingTextarea2" style="height: 100px"></textarea>
            <label for="floatingTextarea2">Please determine appropriate corrective action.</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mt-2 ">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i></span>
            <span class="input-group-text infoHead" style="width:174px;">Responsible Person:</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="employee name" aria-describedby="employee name">
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 

JS
const ca = document.getElementById("success");
const nc = document.getElementById("danger")
var ca1 = document.getElementById("correctiveAction");
nc.addEventListener("click", function(){
   ca1.style.display="block";
})
ca.addEventListener("click", function(){
    ca1.style.display="none"
})


I've attempted to find ways to target the input and to fire within the parent div only, but I'm not finding a way to do so.
Using the JS, I have included only fires the 'corrective action' on the Registration div even when the 'X' is clicked for the Insurance div.

id attribute values must be unique in the document. You cannot "share" them.

a well crafted selector using document.querySelector will allow you to do that, though you still shouldn't have duplicate ID's

Should i target the input type (ie. radio), rather than the ID of the input? Will this allow me to target within the parent div?

So you would like to toggle the "correctiveAction" on or off using radio buttons. First of all, get rid of as many ids as you can -- like commented, they must be unique and to a large extend you don't need them in a form. Instead of using ids, use the name attribute.
I guess, the "correctiveAction" section only should be part of the submitted data if it is "on". Therefor I suggest that you use the fieldset element. When you set the disabled property to true the field elements in that fieldset will not be included. And then you can use the disabled property to hide the fieldset using CSS.
Make an event listener for the change event, not the click event. And then you can use the name property to figure out what should happen. In this specific case you can give the two radio buttons the value 1 and 0, and then set the disabled property for the fielset to the boolean value that results from the radio button.


document.forms.form01.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  switch(e.target.name){
    case 'registration':
    case 'insurance':
      form[`correctiveAction_${e.target.name}`].disabled = !!parseInt(e.target.value);
      break;
  }
});
fieldset {
  border: none;
}

fieldset:disabled {
  display: none;
}

i.fa-check:before {
  font-style: normal;
  content: "✅";
}

i.fa-x:before {
  font-style: normal;
  content: "❎";
}
<form name="form01">
  <div class="accordion-body vehicleBody border border-light-subtle">
    <h3 id="registration" class="mx-3">Current / Valid Vehicle Registration
      <span>
      <label class="btn btn-outline-success rounded-circle">
        <input type="radio" class="btn-check reg" name="registration" value="1" autocomplete="off" checked>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i>
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-outline-danger rounded-circle ms-3">
        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="registration" value="0" autocomplete="off" />
        <i class="fa-solid fa-x"></i>
      </label>
    </span>
    </h3>
    <fieldset class="ms-3" id="correctiveAction_registration" disabled="true">
      <p class="text-center" style="font-weight: 400; padding: 10px; color: crimson; text-decoration: underline;">Corrective Action Required!</p>
      <div class="form-floating correctiveAction">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="floatingTextarea2" style="height: 100px"></textarea>
        <label for="floatingTextarea2">Please determine appropriate corrective action.</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group mt-2 ">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i></span>
        <span class="input-group-text infoHead" style="width:174px;">Responsible Person:</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="employee name" aria-describedby="employee name">
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <!--Insurance Line-->
  <div class="accordion-body vehicleBody border border-light-subtle">
    <h3 id="insurance" class="mx-3">Current / Valid Insurance
      <span>
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success rounded-circle">
          <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="insurance" value="1" autocomplete="off">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-outline-danger rounded-circle ms-3">
          <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="insurance" value="0" autocomplete="off" checked>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-x"></i>
        </label>
      </span>
    </h3>
    <fieldset class="ms-3" name="correctiveAction_insurance">
      <p class="text-center" style="font-weight: 400; padding: 10px; color: crimson; text-decoration: underline;">Corrective Action Required!</p>
      <div class="form-floating correctiveAction">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="floatingTextarea2" style="height: 100px"></textarea>
        <label for="floatingTextarea2">Please determine appropriate corrective action.</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group mt-2 ">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i></span>
        <span class="input-group-text infoHead" style="width:174px;">Responsible Person:</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="employee name" aria-describedby="employee name">
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>



